# Расчет максимально возможного числа команд процессора

Tags: архитектура, cpu

Имеется процессор risc архитектуры с 16 программно доступными регистрами. Все команды, кроме команд с непосредственной адресацией, должны кодироваться с помощью 2х байт. Известно число команд трехадресных - 13, безадресных - 36. Рассчитать

1. Максимально возможное число двухадресных команд
2. Максимально возможное число одноадресных команд
3. Количества одноадресных и двухадресных команд, исходя из их приблизительного равенства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной задаче архитектура RISC или CISC роли не играет. Тут просто математика:

1. 16 -регистров = 2^4 -> 4 бита для кодирования адреса.
2. всего 2 байта на код = 16 бит.
3. не понятно зачем дается информация о трехадресных и безадресных командах. т.к. максимальное количество двухадресных команд = 2^( 16 - 4*2 ) = 256. 16 бит всего 8 бит отдаём на адресацию.
4. максимальное количество одноадресных = 2^( 16 - 4 ) = 4096.
5. по 3-му пункту затрудняюсь ответить. т.к. не совсем понятно.

Скорее всего я что-то упускаю или не правильно понимаю условия, возможно есть ограничения.
и нужно учитывать известное количество команд как ограничения. Пусть автор уточнит.